# Can any one suggest me how to resolve this problem: Error Code : 1064 in MY SQL 5.5 ver

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, user-defined-functions

```
DELIMITER $$;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS tonumeric $$;
CREATE FUNCTION tonumeric() returns numeric
BEGIN
    declare num numeric;
    set num = to_number('12');
    return num;
END$$
DELIMITER; $$
```

When I executed this function, I am facing this error.

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS tonumeric' at line 1
(0 ms taken)

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
CREATE FUNCTION tonumeric() returns numeric
BEGIN
declare num numeric;
set num' at line 1
(0 ms taken)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS tonumeric $$
CREATE FUNCTION tonumeric() returns numeric
BEGIN
    declare num numeric;
    set num = to_number('12');
    return num;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Delimiter is a special command, in that you shouldn't terminate it with a ; -- you're actually setting the delimiter to "$$;", not "$$".